# FaceBook OAuth, Not able to get some of the Email Ids

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a Facebook Oauth application.

For my email account of Facebook it is working fine. 
but for others (my work mates) accounts it is not working.

It is able to get Facebook first name for them but not the email address.

We have checked the settings for all accounts, it is same as me, but not working.

I have also tried in live environment, but the issue is the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the `email` extended permission for the user whose email address you're trying to access? You can check with a call to `/me/permissions` in the graph API

Answer (score 0):

Also consider that you can read real email also depending on your friends's privacy settings

Comment: It's not possible to read the email addresses of a user's friends with any level of access token permissions - only the current user's address can be read, and only with the `email` extended permission